# flask sqlalchemy save/load .h5 file to database

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, h5py

I am trying to save/load .h5 files from a database in flask sqlalchemy, I am using the following code to create the files...

```
#Save file to database
with open('model.h5', 'rb') as filehandler:
    test = Stock(symbol=str(stock.symbol) + 'Model.h5', data=filehandler.read(), isStock=False)
    db.session.merge(test)
    db.session.commit()
```

This is the code I am using to load the file...

```
#Create file from database
with open('model.h5', "wb") as filehandler:
    test = Stock.query.filter_by(symbol=str(stock.symbol) + 'Model.h5').first()
    filehandler.write(test.data)
```

I get a NoneType object has no attribute data error.

Also, data is a LongBlob variable...

```
data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(length=(2**32)-1))
```

Here is the stock model....

```
#File model
class Stock(db.Model):
    symbol = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    isStock = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    prices = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    predictedPrices = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary(length=(2**32)-1))
```

Update: Turns out since I'm running my program in threads it needs to query each instance separately. Which is why I was getting the NoneType error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple threads you will have to query each instance in each thread separately.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code with my h5 file. I obversed that  "db.session.merge(test)" does update the old record as you want, while create a new record!

Comment: I have a print right after i use the merge which seems to be working fine.

Comment: I update my answer!   "merge" maybe not run as you think

Comment: I think before you run 'merge', a primary_key should be assigned to the record

Comment: If that were true wouldn't I get an error saying duplicate primary key, or maybe its cause I'm using global variables and I haven't done a query after this point. Thanks, I'll try implementing a new way.

Comment: Also can you check if the model predicts correctly for you after you load it? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I implemented using db.session.add() and it still displays NoneType object has no attribute data.

Comment: Could you pls show your 'class Stock(db.Model)' code? I want to have another try.